# Unwind Segue Not return to the desired view Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I searched a lot about Unwind segue and their weird behaviour.

I will use these abbreviations to explain my problem:

TabBarController = TBC

NavigationController = NVC

ViewController = VC

I have the following Scenario:

TBC -> NVC -> VC -> Pushed VC -> Pushed VC -> Modal VC -> Modal VC

When I try to perform the Unwind Segue from the last to the first. It stops at last Pushed VC.

Knowing that I am not using shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier in any of them.
Can someone solve this problem please?

Comment: Which VC do you want to unwind *to*? And where is your Unwind Segue function?

Comment: I want to unwind to TBC.
    @IBAction func UnwindToTabBar(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    }
this function is located at TBC Controller

And I Want to unwind from Modal VC (Last VC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, well... if you have

```
TBC -> NVC -> NVCRoot -> Pushed VC1 -> Pushed VC2 -> Modal VCA -> Modal VCB
```

you cannot unwind from VCB to TBC... In fact, you cannot unwind from *anywhere* to TBC.

NVC is a child view controller of TBC - it's *not* a VC "on the segue stack". Likewise, NVCRoot is the root VC of NVC... you are either there, or you have to replace it.

You *should* have no problem unwinding from VCB to VCRoot though, which is, I think, where you *really* want to end up.